# Reason for Grouping the Irrationals

Tags: number-theory, math-history, irrational-numbers

Let me show you my resoning:

- The inverse of addition is subtraction. To complete subtraction, we create the *negative numbers* $(-5)$.
- The inverse of multiplication is division. To complete* division, we create the *fractional numbers* $(3/7)$.
- The inverse** of exponentiation is root. To complete* root, we create the *root numbers* $(√2)$.
- The inverse** of tetration is super-root. To complete* super-root, we create the *super-root numbers* $(Super√57)$.
- And so on with every following hyperoperation.

<sup>*We still have division by zero and square roots of negative numbers, we need other numbers to complete them.
**Also, there are other invseres, the logarithms.</sup>

---

We can then group up the numbers:

- Naturals + Negatives = *Integers*
- Integers + Fractionals = *Rationals*
- Rationals + Roots = *Rootionals*
- Rootionals + Super-roots = *Super-rootionals*...

Except that we don't do this for some reason. Instead, we make a cutoff at multiplication and say, *"everything that isn't rational is irrational. That's it"*. **I was wondering if anyone knows the logic behind such grouping of the numbers, as opposed to the one I expected (which I think is more intuitive).**

---

The only possible reason I could think of, is that rational numbers can be written explicitly, while irrational numbers have infinite decimals so they can't. We can only write, "the number that exponentiatied to itself is $57$". Maybe that's very important to mathematicians, more so that keeping intuition?

Comment: Irrationals are further divided into algebraic and transcendental numbers. Tetration is a highly specialized operations without broad application so super-roots aren't useful enough to be worth defining. Typically definitions must be useful to justify their existence.

Comment: People do group the irrationals.  There are algebraic irrationals (as opposed to transcendental) and so on.

Comment: The completion we need irrationals for is convergence of Cauchy sequences

Comment: FYI, the following is a strictly increasing sequence of classes of irrational real numbers (except the marked ruler numbers and real radical numbers): Pythagorean/Hilbert field numbers, ruler-and-compass constructible numbers, constructible with marked rulers, expressible in terms of real radicals, expressible in terms of radicals, algebraic numbers, elementary in various ways (Joseph Ritt,
Timothy Chow, etc.), provably recursive in various ways, recursive [= computable], various levels of monotonically recursive classes, arithmetical hierarchy, hyper-arithmetical numbers.

Answer (score 3):

To go further beyond the remark made by CyclotomicField in the comment, that’s not necessarily the most fruitful outlook on the study of numbers (though it’s been mostly considered throughout history). For instance, you made mention (in a footnote) of the necessity of other numbers “needed to complete [the square roots of negative numbers]”. This has been done—in the complex numbers.

The root numbers, as you call them, are all special cases of zeroes of polynomial equations, generally of the form $$a_nz^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1z+a_0=0\,,$$ where the coefficients are (for now) integers. These are the “algebraic” numbers; for instance, your root number $\sqrt{2}$ is a solution to the equation $z^2-2=0$. If a number is never the solution to a polynomial equation as above, then they’re called “transcendental”—famous examples are $\pi$ and $e$ (the base of the natural logarithm).

This is a big story which continues today in special and broad subject areas —algebraic number theory, transcendental number theory, arithmetic algebraic geometry, etc.